# ImageFlow + HighSlide dimmingOpacity option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imageflow

I use Imageflow carousel combined with HighSlide image thumbnail viewer. I joined them together as it's described in the documentation [here](http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Combinations). It looks like everything works well. The only thing I can't figure out how to make work is dimmingOpacity option. It fills all the background with the color I set when the image pops up with HighSlide. I did all how it's described in the documentation and tried other variants but couldn't make it work.
The demo page is [here](http://www.aboud-creative.com/demos/larkin/). There is a Products link on the left, clicking on that you will get to the gallery.
What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by replacing **highslide.js** with **highslide-full.js**. Now it works fine.